# heated metal electrons (not) ejected (yes for photoelectric effect)

Tags: photoelectric-effect

I understand that in the case of photoelectricity, electrons can be ejected off the metal. In this case light shines on the metal giving energy to the metal.

But in the case of a heated metal (not by light shining on it), energy is given to the metal, and still electrons should not be ejected. Instead the electrons will start emitting photons.

Question:

1. Why are electrons not (or are they) ejected from the metal when it is heated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Electrons are emitted from heated objects. This is called *thermionic emission* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermionic_emission).